# r data repository to use in Shiny

Tags: shiny, repository

I am working on a shiny app which reads lots of fst files (5gb in total) and makes a large list. Is there any r data repository that I can use in shinyapp so when I make it online it can directly get data from there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I can use in shinyapp": do you mean "I can access from my shiny app" or "I can access from shinyapps.io"?  If the former, where is your app hosted?

Comment: It still on my local computer for now. But it will be on shinyapps.io when I overcome this problem. My app does analysis using this data with user selected parameters.

Comment: That is critical information.  shinyapps.io is containerised, so the only data an app on shinyapps.io has access to is data uploaded in the app bundle, data which the current user uploads, or data which is hosted elsewhere.  3GB/5GB is the [limit](https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/applications.html) on the bundle size.  You'll need to look elsewhere.  AWS is the obvious choice if you don't have an in-house solution.  You'll need to construct an interface between shinyapps.io and your data host.